# compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

After Adding `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/core';` to `app.module.ts` file
 I'm getting

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'
        at syntaxError (compiler.js:2430)
        at compiler.js:18651
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:18620)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:26029)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:26010)
        at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:25970)
        at CompilerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:143)
        at compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ (core.js:17618)
        at PlatformRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:17801)
```

I request community to help me. I'm beginner in Angular-7

Comment: Could you share more code? Where do you use `FormsModule`?

Comment: share your app module code

Comment: import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './products/products.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BookComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    LowerPipe,
  DiscountPipe
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule,FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: Hai here I shared my app.module.ts code

Comment: I found my answer. It was mistake while importing. It is '@angular/forms' not '@angular/core'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```